# In UICollectionView Cell not deselecting when selection is made using cell.isSelected = true

Tags: ios, swift

I am assigning same selection to both the collection view and a 3d model in scenekit on the basis of a boolean value. Same selection is being done. When i select from collection view, i can deselect from both the model and the collection view. But when i select from the 3d model, i cant deselect from collection view. After debugging i have found that after selecting from the 3d model, when i tap the selected cell for deselection it runs the "get" method of the isSelected but not the "set" method. That is why my deselection is not being done.

I have already tried to do it by isHighlighted and didSelect, deSelect but then my same selection doesn't work.

```
override var isSelected: Bool{
    get{
        return super.isSelected
    }
    set{
        let vc = self.window?.rootViewController as? MainViewController
        if newValue{

            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            if self.reuseIdentifier == "mainCollectionCell"{
                super.isSelected = newValue
                super.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
                vc?.viewModel.addingFromMainCollectionView(cell: self)
                let node = vc?.sceneview.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "arm", recursively: true)
                let material = node?.geometry?.material(named: self.name)
                material?.emission.contents = UIColor.red
                vc?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }

        }else{

            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            if self.reuseIdentifier == "mainCollectionCell"{
                super.isSelected = newValue
                super.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true

                vc?.viewModel.removeFromMainCollectionView(cell: self)
                let node = vc?.sceneview.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "arm", recursively: true)
                let material = node?.geometry?.material(named: self.name)
                material?.emission.contents = UIColor.black
                vc?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
```

}

//When making selection from 3d model

```
        if viewModel.allmodels[index].selectornot == true{
            material.emission.contents = UIColor.red

            let cellArray = self.midCollectionView.visibleCells as! [LeftCollectionViewCell]
            if cellArray.contains(where: {$0.name == materialname}){
                let cellIndexPath = cellArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == materialname})
                let cell = cellArray[cellIndexPath as! Int] as! LeftCollectionViewCell
                cell.isSelected  = true
            }
        }
        else{
            material.emission.contents = UIColor.black

            let cellArray = self.midCollectionView.visibleCells as! [LeftCollectionViewCell]
            if cellArray.contains(where: {$0.name == materialname}){
                let cellIndexPath = cellArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == materialname})
                let cell = cellArray[cellIndexPath as! Int] as! LeftCollectionViewCell
                self.midCollectionView.visibleCells[0].isSelected = false
                cell.isSelected = false
            }

        }
```

I expect the cell to be deselected when i tap it, after making selection from 3d model by assigning cell.isSelected = true .